# How to record UTC time in Azure SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, utc

I want to store UTC time in a column in Azure SQL so that I can localize the date time for users of my mobile app regardless of their time zone.  I was using SQL Server 2014 on my local desktop to develop the database which I intend to migrate to Azure SQL.

Now I tried using the type datetimeoffset(7) for my column, however when I insert the date, I see values like this in management studio (with my own local offset value)

> 2016-03-13 18:00:00.0000000 -04:00

Which is a bit confusing because there should be no offset, UTC is always the reference point -00:00 Is this a UTC value or not? Or is SQL Management studio converting them for display to my local time zone?

Furthermore, is my C# code providing the value as UTC or as an offset value?

My C# code used to pass the parameter to my stored procedure looks like this

```
                    string dtFormat = "yyMMdd HHmm";

                    DateTimeOffset dtOut;
                    bool result = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(CurrentUTC.date + " " + CurrentUTC.time, dtFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtOut);

                    command.Parameters.Add("@datetime", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = dtOut;
```

Comment: No, DateTimeOffset is not UTC but it is relative to it. It is generally the best data type when you want to record an instant in time.

Comment: @Crowcoder Maybe I could store it as a string that I know will always be UTC, then parse it to local time on the client application?

Comment: [give this a read](http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html). Dates and time are hard. But I don't think you need to use strings.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks. I have a feeling that when parsing the string, the C# object DateTimeOffset assumes the string is local to wherever you were when you parsed it. For example parse the UTC time stamp 2016-03-13 21:00, there is a property called UtcDateTime which gives a value of 2016-03-14 01:00 which is wrong.  It should be the other way around since I am 4 hours behind UTC at this moment in time.  Now when I convert the parsed string using DateTimeOffset dtUTC = dtOut.ToUniversalTime(); it give the correct result.  The question remaining is how the SQL server will handle that value.

Comment: Stop using strings and you'll save yourself a lot of headaches. What is `CurrentUTC` and why are you not using it directly for the parameter value?

Answer (score 1):

For my Azure apps, I just use a datetime field in Azure SQL and then in C# use DateTime.UtcNow for the value of that field.

When reading it back out, I use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc() with the local user's timezone string.